# How to color first strong element within P tag one color and the rest another color?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to get :first-of-type to work for the `<strong>` HTML element but it won't work.

There can be numerous (random number and placement, but within p tags) `<strong>` elements but I want the first one to have different text color than the rest.

Here I would expect Hello 1 to be blue and Hello 2 + Hello 3 to be yellow. But they're all blue.

```css
.yolo p strong { color:yellow; }
.yolo p strong:first-of-type { color:blue; }
```

```html
<div class="yolo">
    <p>bla bla</p>
    <p><strong>Hello 1</strong></p>
    <p>bla bla</p>
    <p><strong>Hello 2</strong></p>
    <p>bla bla</p>
    <p>bla bla</p>
    <p><strong>Hello 3</strong></p>
</div>
```

[JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rassom/hhLzpb2q/4/)

Any ideas?

Solution doesn't have to include `:first-of-type` as long as the HTML remains unchanged.

Comment: There are typos in your fiddle that may or may not be related to the problem. Also, you need to include the fiddle code within the question so readers aren't forced to click the link to see the context.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference but thanks for catching that. I've been playing around with it quite a bit to have it work so I guess I must have made the type before sharing. Now fixed. Didn't know that it was possible to include the code in the way that it is now, so have updated the question. Thanks for pointing it out and maybe a little bit quick to downvote, btw?

Comment: Yeah, just wanted to make sure your test case is accurate. That wasn't my downvote, though - have an upvote as proof now that you've edited the code in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, each `<strong>` element is the first of its element type in its own parent `<p>`, therefore both elements match the `:first-of-type` pseudo-class.

Unfortunately, in this case, you may be stuck. Since the first `<strong>` element may not necessarily appear in the first `<p>` element as shown in your markup, you won't be able to use something like `.yolo p:first-of-type strong` to target the first `<strong>`. Neither is there a way using CSS to target just the first element in such a structure, since the existing structural pseudo-classes only match the nth element among its siblings, and [there is no parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) so you can't write a selector finding "the first `<p>` element that contains a `<strong>` element".

Since your markup is produced by a CMS, you will have to either

- tell the CMS to apply a class name either to the first paragraph containing a `<strong>` element or to the first `<strong>` element, or
- use JavaScript to apply the class name if the behavior of the CMS cannot be modified

then target this class.

Comment: I understand. Bummer! :(  Will see if someone comes up with a supercreative solution but it seems like it's not possible. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

From [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-of-type/):

> The :first-of-type selector in CSS allows you to target the first occurence of an element within its container. It is defined in the CSS Selectors Level 3 spec as a “structural pseudo-class”, meaning it is used to style content based on its relationship with parent and sibling content.

This means that this will work:

```
<div class="yolo">
    <p><strong>Strong 1</strong>
    <br>
    <strong>Strong 2</strong></p>
</div>
```

But this wont:

```
<div class="yolo">
    <p><strong>Strong 1</strong></p>
    <p><strong>Strong 2</strong></p>
</div>
```

Because in the second example each of the `<strong>` is the first in its `<p>` container. But in the first example, the two `<strong>` tags are both in the same `<p>` container, so Strong 1 goes blue, being the first one in the paragraph, and Strong 2 goes yellow, not being the the first in the paragraph.

Comment: Don't forget to link to the source. Simply naming it is not enough if the original source is readily available online.

Comment: Thanks @CalvT - but I can't change the HTML code unfortunately (CMS system) - can you make your answer work on the HTML code I have, please?

Comment: Thanks @CalvT - appreciate your efforts :)  But I don't know if the strong element are in the HTML, only that they are wrappen in p tags. I.e. there could be no "bla bla" between Hello 2 and Hello 3.

Comment: Yeah I wondered that, but unless you know the structure of your HTML, and so you can use the `nth-of-type` and number the one it is there is no other way to target it using only css